# Отрицательное число в массиве byte

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, создаю байт массив, возникает ошибка на элемент -35

```
byte[] index = new byte[] { 0, -35, 0 };
Значение константы "-35" не может быть преобразовано в "byte".
```

Comment: тип `byte` принимает строго положительные числа 0..255. Если нужно представление со знаком, используйте `sbyte` -128..+127. Читать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables)

Comment: @rdorn, почему не ответом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тип `byte` принимает строго положительные числа 0..255. Если нужно представление со знаком, используйте тип `sbyte` -128..+127. Читать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables)